# Angular 7 polling/get from an API every interval for response code

Tags: typescript, api, angular7, polling, rxjs6

I'm making a front end GUI for an API. One of the steps in this tool is polling an app for multifactor authentication, etc. I don't deal with that.

I'm trying to make an Angular 7 function that polls or calls this HTTP GET `/getmfa` API every 5 seconds until the MFA goes through and API gives me a JSON.

I'm having trouble getting interval to work. The internet is full of conflicting info with RxJS versions and `.pipe` syntax. I'm using RxJS 6+ and Angular 7

First I tried to get interval to work

```
    poll(apiUrl: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
        let url = apiUrl;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        let httpOptions = {
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: true,
        };

        return interval(5000).pipe(map(() => {
            return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
                .pipe(
                    map(
                        (data) => {
                            console.log('polling...');
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        },
                        error => {
                            console.log('Error:', error);
                        }
                    )
                )
        }));
```

Even timeout doesn't work, but it's not what I want anyway.

```
    poll(apiUrl: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
        let url = apiUrl;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        let httpOptions = {
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: true,
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                (data) => {
                    return data;
                }
            )
          }, 5000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what didn't work in the first approach with `interval`?

Comment: is the first approach the correct one? im uncertain

Comment: `interval` is probably preferred over `setTimeout` or even `setInterval` as it's easier to connect into the rest of an app's existing RxJS infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to [SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) between your interval observable and the http observable.

```js
  return interval(5000).pipe(
      switchMap(counter => {
        return this.http.get(ulr, httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            catchError(error => this.handleError(error)
            )
          );
      })
    );
```